# Can stellar.js readjust element offsets on window resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to reinitialize stellar.js on browser/window resize so that the element offsets get readjusted?

Answer (score 14):

First of all, it sounds like you might be having an issue with horizontal alignment (assuming it's a vertical site). If so, it's likely that you only need to disable horizontal scrolling:

```
$.stellar({
    horizontalScrolling: false
});
```

If this doesn't solve your issue, Stellar.js has an undocumented feature that allows you to refresh the plugin.

For example, let's assume you used Stellar.js like this:

```
$.stellar();
```

You can refresh it with the following:

```
$.stellar('refresh');
```

So, to refresh it on resize, you could do something like this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $.stellar('refresh');
});
```

Hopefully this should fix everything for you.

Answer (score 13):

After a bit of sleuthing, I've figured this one out. In my case, I have 'slides', which contain my stellar elements, and they are sized to full width/height of the viewport. I needed to resize them for tablet orientation change.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    winHeight = $(window).height();
    $("#scrollWrapper > div").height(winHeight);

    // Find out all my elements that are being manipulated with stellar
    var particles = $(window).data('plugin_stellar').particles;

    // Temporarily stop stellar so we can move our elements around
    // data('plugin_stellar') let's me access the instance of stellar
    // So I can use any of its methods. See stellar's source code
    $(window).data('plugin_stellar').destroy();

    $.each(particles, function(i, el){
        // destroy() sets the positions to their original PIXEL values. 
        // Mine were percentages, so I need to restore that.
        this.$element.css('top', '');

        // Once the loop is finished, re-initialize stellar
        if(particles.length - 1 == i){
            $(window).data('plugin_stellar').init();
        }
    });
});
```

If it doesn't matter that the elements get set to their original pixel values for left/top, then you can just call destroy & init one after the other:

```
$(window).data('plugin_stellar').destroy();
$(window).data('plugin_stellar').init();
```

If you instantiate stellar on an element (i.e., `$("#element").stellar();` instead of `$.stellar();`) then replace "window" with your selector.

Comment: I was in pretty much the exact situation here, thanks for this! This should be included in the function as some sort of function, the out of the box refresh doesn't help in in this instance, I think it has something to do with using percentages.

Answer (score 7):

I also noticed odd offsets on mobiles that may be caused by the way Firefox/Chrome resizes the webview when scrolling down, when the location bar becomes visible again?

The answer to your question is in a section of the [documentation](http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/docs/#configuration): "Configuring everything":

```
// Refreshes parallax content on window load and resize
responsive: false,
```

So, this is false by default. To enable this, use `.stellar( {responsive:true} )`

The real question is... why is this disabled by default? It seemed to fix the problem I was noticing, except for iOS.